# How to delete dates between two date range without deleting the entire row?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a schedule page where a employee can insert their vacation time off, and delete data for that particular date range.

I have two textboxes that are for the date range, and I have try using the code below but it only deletes the entire row if the date ranges matches, and not the data in-between. HELP?

```
    protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (StartTextBox.Text == "" || EndTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please Enter a Date Range to Submit for employee.');", true);
        }
        string find = "DELETE FROM Schedule where start >= @DateTo AND end_date <= @DateFrom";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(find, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = StartTextBox.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = EndTextBox.Text;   

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Time-off submitted successfully!');", true);
    }
```

Comment: What does a row of the data look like? I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: I think you have your args backwards.  You want `start >= @DateFrom AND end_date <= @DateTo`.

Comment: What you mean by `not the data in-between`?

Comment: What @BradleyUffner said.

Comment: maybe you mean this? `start >= @DateFrom AND end_date <= @DateTo`

Comment: First use `DateTime` datatype and not `NVarchar`, other than that, your query would probably delete schedule for all users and not just for current user, *(or may be there is DB design that is taking care of that*)

Comment: Congratulations on actually using parameterized queries though!  You deserve a gold star for that.

Comment: start & end_date are strings in the database.. and I mean that if I have a date range 08-01-16 & 08-05-16... And someone wanted to enter their vacation date as 08-01-16 through 08-03-16 how do I delete their vacation time without deleting the entire row?

Comment: You *really* need to consider changing the field type in the database to one of the date formats.  You also really need to find a better way to explain "without deleting the entire row" because we have no clue what you mean by that, even with your new example.

Comment: Further example: If I have a row A with start is: 07-27-16 and end_date is: 08-04-16... I want to delete the time-off date (07-27-16 for start and 08-01-16 for end_date) IN-BETWEEN the already existing row A. Is there a way to delete and update the row so after I insert the time-off date row A is now: 08-02-16 for start and 08-04-16 for end_date?

Answer (score 2):

You are using nvarchar as a data type. The behavior of < and > is not what you'd expect.

Consider changing the column type to *datetime*

After that you can change the code to:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(StartTextBox.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(EndTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it is still only deleting the entire row.

Comment: Further example: If I have a row A with start is: 07-27-16 and end_date is: 08-04-16... I want to delete the time-off date (07-27-16 for start and 08-01-16 for end_date) IN-BETWEEN the already existing row A. Is there a way to delete and update the row so after I insert the time-off date row A is now: 08-02-16 for start and 08-04-16 for end_date?

Comment: It's supposed to delete 'the entire row'. That is, every single row matching your 'where' clause. Any row in the 'schedule' table with a value on column 'start' after or same as your argument 'DateTo' and value on column 'end_date' before or equal to 'DateFrom' parameter. Isn't that what you are trying to achieve?